# input button causes RequiredFieldValidator to fire

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, input-button-image

I have an input button on my page that is dynamically created, every time I press it, it fires the RequiredFieldValidator for the blank field in the email address.
is there a way to ovverride it?

input code:

```
<input class=\"hledat\" id=\"searchbutton\" type=\"image\" src=\"search-button.gif\" value=\"{0}\" onclick=\"search('{1}');\" onkeypress=\"search('{1}');\"/>"
```

validator code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="98%" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="email"
    Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="newsletter" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="email"
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="dynamic"
    ValidationGroup="newsletter" />
```

Comment: What does `search`? Apart from that, "black field" means "blank field"? I assume you want to postback without validating, don't you?

Comment: are you trying to perform any JS operation in this with Search?

Comment: actually no, should I try to create a server button instead ?

Comment: just add runat="server" to your input button.

Comment: it kicks the validator because a click on the `input` causes a postback. It's unclear from your question whether you actually want it to postback or whether you just want it to do the js on the `onclick` handler. Can you clarify this?

Comment: yes, i want it to do a postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an input button on my page that is dynamically created, every
>   time I press it, it fires the RequiredFieldValidator for the blank
>   field in the email address. is there a way to ovverride it?

[**HtmlButton.CausesValidation Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.causesvalidation%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

### Mark UP

`<button causesvalidation="false" /><button ID="StateQueryButton"
        CausesValidation="False"
        runat="server">
    Submit
</button>`

---

> yes, i want it to do a postback

**[HtmlButton.OnServerClick Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

### Code Behind

```
protected void FancyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  

}
```

### Mark Up

`<button causesvalidation="false" /><button ID="StateQueryButton"
        CausesValidation="False"
        OnServerClick=" FancyBtn_Click"
        runat="server" >
    Submit
</button>`

Comment: thank
and I changed the input type to button instead of image

Answer (score 1):

Make it server side button by writing **runat="Server"** attribute and make a **CausesValidation="true|false"** on your requirements. If you do false it will not validate. Do let me know if it solves the problem

Comment: You should not use **Signature** in post. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0):

try to add **runat="server"** to input button as shown:

*Note* *the runat="server". While asp:button probably renders similarly, if what you really want it an HTML button input, you can use that. Yes, ASP.NET will pick up the value on the server side.***

```
<input type="button" runat="server" id="btnTest" value="change" onclick="doPostBack('btnTest', '');"/>
```

Comment: I think you may try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx